# Sending multiple SMS and emails with Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, email, xamarin.ios, sms

I'm developing an iPhone application with MonoTouch framework and I'm trying to send multiple SMS and emails in one shot.
A sort of

```
foreach (User user in userList)
{
    SendSMS(user.TelephoneNumber);
    SendEmail(user.EmailAddress);
}
```

I've found samples about [sending SMS](http://psuh.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/sending-textsms-with-monotouch/) and [emails](http://psuh.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/sending-emails-with-monotouch/), but each time, the author uses a `MFMessageComposeViewController` and `MFMailComposeViewController`.

I don't want a ViewController, just sending SMS / emails while my "loading alert view" shows process status.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for the help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS doesn't allow you to send e-mails or texts without user interaction.

If you want to do this you will need to use a third party service for SMTP and SMS.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your answer. After many hours search, I've found nothing else. It seems you are right. There is CTMessageCenter (from CoreTelephony) but it means no AppStore and it's in Obj-C, so useless with Monotouch. Can you explain me more about 3rd party service ?

Comment: google "SMS API" for a list of SMS services, like Twilio.  They provide an API you can use to send messages from your app.  You can use a similar approach with mail.  There are mail services that expose APIs you can use to send mail, or you can just send mail via SMTP if you have access to an SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I'm going to investigate this point. I'll give my feed back.

Comment: At the end, I had to use a webservice for emails and subscribe to SMS service. And it works great. Thanks !